# How to load external javascript file first before using it in BODY onload event?

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="folder/externaljs.js">
</head>

<body onload="someFunctionInExternalJS();">
</body>
```

How do I ensure that *externaljs.js* is loaded first so that `someFunctionInExternalJS()` is executed as a result? Thanks!

Comment: "How do I ensure?" Test it!

Comment: Tested ... not working

Comment: would you like to show the `someFunctionInExternalJS();` function?

Comment: That's just an example it could be any function in externaljs.js file

Comment: technically it should work in my opinion think of the jquery functions how does they work??

Comment: I think it has something to do with browser's loading mechanism

Comment: call your JS function inside `window.onload` event instead

Comment: show us the contents of externaljs.js, everything shown works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this code and it works fine :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="my_script.js"></script>
 </head>
<body onload="my_function()">

</body>
</html>
```

with this in my_script.js :

```
function my_function () {
    alert("Hello world!");
    }
```

Another solution is to write this in my_script.js :

```
function my_function () {
    alert("Hello world!");
    }

document.onload = my_function();
```

Answer (score 2):

The external javascript file will load and execute before continuing along and building the DOM,  unless it is async (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp).

Any external file that the DOM requires to build (javascript, css primarily) will load as it is being parsed.  This is why you will sometimes see javascript at the bottom of the body tag instead of the head.

Answer (score 2):

using jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //anything in here will only be called/work when the document is ready.

 //call your function in here, instead of bodyonload
});
```